# Nmap: what is the difference between "nmap <target>" and "nmap -sS <target>"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, security, unix

This is an extremely basic question but also one I can't really seem to find an answer for, despite looking through the nmap documentation (man, online, and google).

My question is, what is the difference between doing `nmap <target>` and `nmap -sS <target>`, for example?  I know that `-sS` is a TCP SYN scan, but I guess what I am not sure of is how/why this differs from just scanning ports using `nmap <target>`?

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference.  Per the man page -sS is the default scan type (usually.. see the man page for exceptions).  I've confirmed this with a tcpdump.

Answer (score 5):

`-sS` will force nmap to perform a SYN scan. Don't specifying a scan type will let nmap choose the best one.

If you're running nmap as a privileged user (typically: root), SYN scan will be selected by default. In this case there is no difference between both command lines (with or without `-sS`).

If you're running nmap as a simple user, SYN scan won't be available, in this case `-sS` will likely fail and the simple command `nmap <target>` command line will perform a TCP connect scan (equivalent of `-sT`).

If your system allows it you can force nmap to act as if it was (or not) privileged using `--privileged` or `--unprivileged`.

Comment: I don't remember, but won't `nmap` do ICMP echo when hosts are on different subnet and ARP requests when they are if no options are specified? Or is it an "on unless specified otherwise" option?

Answer (score 2):

man nmap

```
 -sS (TCP SYN scan)
              SYN scan is the default and most popular scan option ...
```

Comment: In response to your updated question: no difference.

Answer (score 0):

-sS named "TCP SYN (Stealth) scan" (SYN,SYN-ACK,RST) is used by default for privileged (admin,root) user: there is no need to specify it.

Otherwise -sT named "TCP Connect scan" (full TCP handshake:SYN,SYN-ACK,ACK) is used for standard user, this is not as fast and stealthy.

Using -sS with standard (unprivileged) user will result in a failure as it required raw-packet privileges.

Using --packet-trace option will nmap will show you what happen at a low level and demonstrates the differences between -sT and -sS.